# Django - How to Validate Data by Name

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a formset that I recently added an autocomplete text box with jQuery in one of the fields. The autocomplete is a text box that auto completes text based on the product names. Since it is a text field and not a select field like I had before, I need to type in the PK in order for the form to actually validate correctly. I tried adding a custom cleaning function that queries the database by the entered name and outputs the correct object, but django validation seems to not even run my cleaning, and rejects the form before my cleanign function can even run.

Please forgive some of the code here that doesn't seem to make much sense, I'm new. Any help is greatly appreciated!

If it helps I included my code below.

views.py

```
def create_orderproduct_view(request, pk=None):
    order_number = get_object_or_404(Order, pk=pk)
    OrderProductFormSet = formset_factory(OrderProductForm)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = OrderProductFormSet(request.POST)
        for x in formset:
            if x.is_valid() and 'Product_ID' in x.cleaned_data:
                x.save()
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('orderproduct', kwargs={'pk':pk}))
    else:
        formset = OrderProductFormSet()
    return render(request, 'create_orderproduct.html', {'formset': formset})
```

forms.py

```
class OrderProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderProduct
        exclude = ('ID',)
        widgets = {
            'Product_ID' : AutoCompleteWidget()
        }
    def clean_Product_ID(self):
        Product_ID = self.cleaned_data['Product_ID']
        clean = Product.objects.get(Name__exact=Product_ID)
        return clean
```

widgets.py

```
#my custom widget
class AutoCompleteWidget(Widget):
    template_name = "widgets/auto_complete.html"

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        return {'widget' : {
            'name' : name,
            'value' : value,
        }}

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        context = self.get_context(name, value, attrs)
        template = loader.get_template(self.template_name).render(context)
        return mark_safe(template)
```

The Autocomplete Box

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
      $( function() {
        var availableTags = [
            'item 1',
            'item 2',
            'item 3',
            'item 4',
        ];
        $( ".my_class_name" ).autocomplete({
          source: availableTags
        });
      } );
  </script>

<input class='my_class_name' name="{{widget.name}}" id="{{widget.name}}" type='text'>
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this for a couple days, I managed to find a pretty easy solution that I'm not quite sure how I missed. I took the request.POST and used regular expressions to filter the fields that had my autocomplete on it. I did a query for the name of the entry and saved over it to save the pk instead of my item name. This seems to be a pretty good way at bypassing the Django validation because you are changing the results of the data being fed into the validation.

Code below for anyone else who was struggling with this:
DISCLAIMER: I do not know if this is the best way to do this, nor can I guarantee that it will be error free. Use at your own risk.

views.py

```
def regex_query(request):
    pattern = re.compile(r'form.\d+.Product_ID')
    ## this is the name of my individual form
    post = request.POST.copy()
    for x in post:
        matcher = re.match(pattern, x)
        if matcher and post[x]:
            clean = Product.objects.get(Name__exact=post[x])
            post[x] = clean.pk

    return post 


def create_orderproduct_view(request, pk=None):
    OrderProductForm().fields['Room'].choices
    order_list = []
    order_number = get_object_or_404(Order, pk=pk)
    OrderProductFormSet = formset_factory(OrderProductForm)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ## using regular expressions to identify the product, then query the result of the key to change the data
        request.POST = regex_query(request)
        ## saving over the request.POST
        formset = OrderProductFormSet(request.POST)
        for x in formset:
            if x.is_valid() and 'Product_ID' in x.cleaned_data:
                x.save()
... continues below ...
```